# Takeing unique values from one column in table

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I am a beginner in Hashkell ​​and Yesod, and I am interested in how to take all the unique values ​​
from one column in the mysql table.
A concrete example is that I have an Address entity and I want to take all the values ​​for the city attribute :

```
Address json
    state Text sqltype=varchar(255)
    city Text sqltype=varchar(255)
    street Text Maybe sqltype=varchar(255)
    number Text sqltype=varchar(255)
    deriving Show Typeable
```

I want to pick up all the values ​​of the city to use them in the form.
I would like to have these values ​​in the dropdown list:

```
filters <- runInputPost $ ManFilter
        <$> iopt (selectFieldList city) "City"
    defaultLayout [whamlet | <h1> # {show $ filters} |]
 where
  city ​​:: [(Text, Text)]
  city ​​= [("NY", "NY"), ("London", "London"), ("Madrid", "Madrid")]
```

And another question how to automatically create a tuple `city :: [(Text, Text)]` from the
values ​​I would get from the database?

If anyone can help I would be grateful, because I'm pretty stuck with the forms.
Also write if it is a good procedure, what is wrong and of course any advice is welcome.
Thank you!

Comment: The straightforward SQL query would be something like `select city from address group by city`. A quick glance through [the Yesod book section on Persistent](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent) doesn't mention anything that looks like a group-by query, so you may be out of luck. Score another one for the YesSQL movement.

Comment: That said... how are you imagining the first `Address` gets into the database? If you only present previously-used cities as options, you're gonna have no options to begin with.

Comment: By running the sql script, I initially populate the database with some test data. Among those data are addresses, where I want to get cities that are unique, ie without duplicates.
Since I had already created a select field in the hamlet file, I decided to use input forms.
And in the hamlet file, I want to list those cities that the user would choose and that I would take in the post handler.